# Listener for addition/deletion of row in JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Is there any event available which will get fired after addition/deletion of rows from JTable ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

On the table itself, no, but the `TableModel` is responsible of fire appropriate events when the model changes.

You can register a `TableModelListener` on the `TableModel`

```
JTable table = new JTable();
table.getModel().addTableModelListener(new TableModelListener() {

        @Override
        public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {
            if (e.getType()==TableModelEvent.INSERT||e.getType()==TableModelEvent.DELETE) {
                // Do something
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, a [TableModelEvent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/event/TableModelEvent.html) gets fired whenever rows are added or deleted.

you need to create a [TableModelListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/event/TableModelListener.html) and then add it to your TableModel using [addTableModelListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/AbstractTableModel.html#addTableModelListener%28javax.swing.event.TableModelListener%29).

If you implemented your own TableModel, make sure that you call `fireTableRowsDeleted(int firstRow, int lastRow)` or `fireTableRowsInserted(int firstRow, int lastRow)` after you add or remove rows.

For instance:

```
theTable.getModel().addTableModelListner(yourTableListener);
```

Where `yourTableListener` is an instance of a class that implements the TableModelListener interface.